# Is there a library to parse java command line options into an associative array?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, associative-array

I need a library which can take command line options of the form  `java -jar --aaa=a --bbb=b ---ccc=c` and return an array whose values can be accessed as `argsArray['aaa'], argsArray['bbb']` etc.

Is there some library with examples to do this?

Comment: *"I don't know much Java but I need it fast."* -1  So hire someone (pay them top rate to reflect your urgency) & stop bothering people on public forums who will answer *if* they feel like it, *when* they are good & ready.

Comment: @Andrew_Thompson My question is whether a library exists that does what I need out of the box, with some sample code. Anyone with knowledge of the answer only needs to point me to it. The programming I am writing does not use any Java at all and just needs a few lines to work with a Java based libraries.

Comment: @davogotland I'm not familiar with stackoverflow etiquette, but what if the answers aren't exactly what you seek? e.g looking at the Related questions, this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259143/split-a-string-containing-command-line-parameters-into-a-string-in-java and http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/tools/ant/types/Commandline.html#translateCommandline%28String%29 are a closer match. I'm not unappreciative of the top answer here, but do I accept an answer when a better one might exist? I am a total Java newbie, but a closer solution exists, perhaps edit the question?

Comment: @vfclists: my answer answers your question. You requested a library and example code; and I have provided you with both. Not only that but the Commons CLI is the benchmark lib for this. What more do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great parser for command line options in Java is the [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/).

Options can have arguments or not, can be optional or required, and you can set up descriptions for each for usage help. A brief example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Options options = new Options();

   try {
      options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("help").hasArgs(0).withDescription("Prints this help message.").isRequired(false).create("h"));
      options.addOption(OptionBuilder.withArgName("debug logging").hasArgs(0).withDescription("Enable debug logging").isRequired(false).create("1"));

      CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
      CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, args);

      if (cmd.hasOption("h")) {
         new HelpFormatter().printHelp(400, "load_page_spool.sh", "OPTIONS", options, "Loads crawl data from pages pool, updating FRONTIER, HISTORY and PageTable", true);
         return;
      }

      ....

   } catch (MissingOptionException e) {
       HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
       formatter.printHelp("LoadPageSpool", options);
   }


}
```

Comment: i read the question as asking about a library that simply parse what's there and return a data structure *without stating the names / symbols you're looking for*. if this lib does so, the example doesn't show it. pretty much every language has the shown functionality, but finding the requested functionality seems much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/).

Another simple solution might be the helper class presented in [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2004/jw-0816-command.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you keep them in a specific order you can access them from the string array that is the parameter for the main method.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option to parse command lines would be [jcommander](http://jcommander.org/). I haven't used it myself but the examples on the website look good and easy to use.