# RegEx to split command line arguments

Tags: java, regex, command-line-arguments

I have a simple Java application that's a GUI for a command line application, and I have a field where the user can add additional command line arguments. The thing is, I want to pass all arguments to an "option file" the CLI application uses, but to do that I need to split each argument accordingly.

An example:

```
--edit info --set title=My Title 1 --edit track:v1 --set flag-default=0 --set flag-forced=0
```

Must become

```
--edit
info
--set
title=My Title 1
--edit
track:v1
--set
flag-default=1
--set
flag-forced=0
```

I basically need a RegEx that will match this:
--set[MATCH]title=My Title 1[MATCH]--edit[MATCH]track:v1

I don't know if this is simple or not, I tried several RegEx arguments but it was way over my head.

The CLI application is mkvpropedit, by the way.

Comment: `--set title=test 1 --edit track:v1`: How do you delimit the title?

Comment: Does it have to be a regexp? I would try Commons ClI http://commons.apache.org/cli/

Comment: @jpalecek: the option file doesn't need quotes for the title, it'll actually treat quotes as literal quotes.

Comment: JCommander can do command-line parsing like above elegantly

Comment: I'll look into it.
I also found a simple solution that I could make work.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3260112/1204179)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you need a regexp here...

In case you're not constrained by some requirement that I don't understand I really think that to parse [GNU style](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch10s05.html) command line options you need to use GNU utility `getopt`, its [Java version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt#Java) in particular.

If you're using Maven using it [boils down](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/gnu.getopt/java-getopt/1.0.13) to adding this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>gnu.getopt</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-getopt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is not restricted to regex then you may find this [command line argument parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java) useful to achieve what you want. It provides better ways than regex to do this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I couldn't really split on the argument as a delimiter because then I wouldn't know what each argument was.  I ended up doing it this way:

```
/**
 * This method takes the command line arguments and turns them back into a single string.
 * Then it looks for argument identifiers and values.  In my case the arguments were
 * like --action (or the synonym -a), --properties (or -p), etc.
 * 
 * I only needed the first letter of the argument for my purposes but you can adjust
 * the regex pattern to return more of group(1) if you need it.
 *
 * @param args
 */
private HashMap<String,String> parseArguments(String[] args){
    HashMap<String,String> rawArguments = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String input = new String();
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        input+=args[i]+" ";
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?-([A-z])[A-z]* (.*?)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    String key=null;
    String val=null;
    int re=0;
    int st=0;
    while(matcher.find()){
        st=matcher.start();
        if(key!=null){
            val=input.substring(re, st).trim();
            rawArguments.put(key,val);
        }

        key=matcher.group(1);
        if(!matcher.hitEnd()){
            re=matcher.end();
        }
    }
    val=input.substring(re).trim();
    rawArguments.put(key,val);

    return rawArguments;        
}
```

Answer (score -3):

As far as I understand you just have to split string using space as a separator. In this case do the following: `str.split("\\s+")`.

Comment: That wouldn't work because some arguments can have spaces, like "--set title=My Title 1".