# How to split a command line like string?

Tags: java, regex

Basically, I need to split the string like

```
"one quoted argument" those are separate arguments "but not \"this one\""
```

to get in result the list of arguments

- "one quoted argument"
- those
- are
- separate
- "but not \"this one\""

This regex `"(\"|[^"])*"|[^ ]+` nearly does the job but the issue is that regular expression always (at least in java) tries to match the **longest** string possible.

In consequence, when I apply the regex to a string that starts and ends with a quoted arguments, it matches the whole string and does not create a group for each argument.

Is there a way to tweak this regex or the [matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) or the [pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) or whatever to handle that?

Note: don't tell me I could use `GetOpt` or `CommandLine.parse` or anything else similar.
**My concern is about pure java regex (if possible but I doubt it...).**

Comment: I don't think it's possible with regular expressions, but I may be wrong.

Comment: What about using `*?` so that the regular expression is not greedy. `"(\\"|[^"])*?"|[^ ]+` matches what you need.

Comment: @Alex If you make that an answer I'll upvote it

Comment: How should it handle `"one quoted argument" those are separate arguments "but not \\"this one\\""`?

Comment: @Alex, thanks, non greedy quantifiers are the solutions !

Comment: A. R. S. is correct, you can't use Java (Perl 5 Compatible) regular expressions to parse the full set of possible command lines.  The reason is that the escaping you're referring to can nest recursively.  You will either need a parser, or a different regular expression engine (see the regex system in newer versions of Perl, which can do this).

Comment: @ZNK-M I added the comment as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the non greedy qualifier `*?` to make it work:

```
"(\\"|[^"])*?"|[^ ]+
```

See this link for an example in action: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?32srs

Comment: Suggestion: replace `[^ ]+` with `[^\s]+`, so it can handle tabs or other whitespace characters

Answer (score 4):

> regular expression always (at least in java) tries to match the
>   longest string possible.

Um... no.

That is controlled by if you use greedy or non-greedy expressions. See [some examples](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/GreedyAndNonGreedyMatching.shtml). Using a non-greedy one (by adding a question mark) should do it. It's called [lazy quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification).

The default is greedy, but it certainly doesn't mean it is always that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String[] parseCommand( String cmd )
{
    if( cmd == null || cmd.length() == 0 )
    {
        return new String[]
        {};
    }

    cmd = cmd.trim();
    String regExp = "\"(\\\"|[^\"])*?\"|[^ ]+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( regExp, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( cmd );
    List< String > matches = new ArrayList< String >();
    while( matcher.find() ) {
        matches.add( matcher.group() );
    }
    String[] parsedCommand = matches.toArray(new String[] {});
    return parsedCommand;
}
```

Comment: Maybe throw NPE on null ? Also you should cache the pattern as per [Markus answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22472588/281545) - and `cmd.length() == 0` will be taken care by the regex

Comment: @Igor this is a great start at the problem, but doesn't work for the last case.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this one (thanks Alex for giving me the good starting point :))

```
/**
 * Pattern that is capable of dealing with complex command line quoting and
 * escaping. This can recognize correctly:
 * <ul>
 * <li>"double quoted strings"
 * <li>'single quoted strings'
 * <li>"escaped \"quotes within\" quoted string"
 * <li>C:\paths\like\this or "C:\path like\this"
 * <li>--arguments=like_this or "--args=like this" or '--args=like this' or
 * --args="like this" or --args='like this'
 * <li>quoted\ whitespaces\\t (spaces & tabs)
 * <li>and probably more :)
 * </ul>
 */
private static final Pattern cliCracker = Pattern
    .compile(
       "[^\\s]*\"(\\\\+\"|[^\"])*?\"|[^\\s]*'(\\\\+'|[^'])*?'|(\\\\\\s|[^\\s])+",
       Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: Will be using it and test. FWIW here is the implementation of [translateCommandline](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/exec/CommandLine.html) - line 337 - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259143/split-a-string-containing-command-line-parameters-into-a-string-in-java