# Splitting a command line in Java

Tags: java, parsing, command-line-interface

What's the recommended way to parse a shell-like command line in Java. By that I don't mean processing the options when they are already in array form (e.g. handling "-x" and such), there are loads of questions and answers about that already.

No, I mean the splitting of a full command string into "tokens". I need to convert a string such as:

```
user 123712378 suspend "They are \"bad guys\"" Or\ are\ they?
```

...to the list/array:

```
user
123712378
suspend
They are "bad guys"
Or are they?
```

I'm currently just doing a split on whitespace, but that obviously can't handle the quotes and escaped spaces.

(Quote handling is most important. Escaped spaces would be nice-to-have)

Note: My command string is the input from a shell-like web interface. It's not built from `main(String[] args)`

Comment: Wouldn't most of those command line libraries have solved this problem?  You could just look at their source.

Comment: @tieTYT As far as I know those libraries only deal with the arguments once they have been separated by the shell. They are for building commands, not shells.

Comment: How would you split the following?: `This is"an example"`. I.e. how would you treat an opening quotation mark preceded by a non-white space character?

Comment: @Lonenebula "This","is","an example"

Comment: Assuming you want the same rules as the shell uses, **this is"an example"** would parse into **this** and **isan example**

Comment: I'd also need some handy lib for this, something like 'shellwords' are for Ruby (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html ) packaged in the default distribution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string containing command-line parameters into a String\[\] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259143/split-a-string-containing-command-line-parameters-into-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would need is to implement a finite automaton. You would need to read the string character by character and find the next state depending on your next or previous character.
For example a `"` indicates start of a string but if it is preceded by an `\` leaves the current state unchanged and reads until the next token that takes you to the next state.
I.e. essentially in your example you would have

```
read string -> read number   
      ^  -    -   -  |
```

You of course would need to define all the states and the special characters that affect or not affect your state.
To be honest I am not sure why you would want to provide such functionality to the end user.
Traditionally all the cli programs accept input in a standard format `-x or --x or --x=s` etc.
This format is well known to a typical user and is simple to implement and test as correct.
Traditionally if we are required to provide more "flexible" input for the user, it is best to build a GUI. That is what I would suggest.

Comment: Well, that's pretty easy to build (and I have in the past, for other situations), but I was hoping some library already fixed it. Regarding the reason, I'm not juist building the commands themselves (that's where -x and such come in, and they might well do in my application), but I'm first building the shell itself, where power users enter command strings via a web interface.

Comment: Perhaps there is a library for what you want, but I am not aware of one to suggest.But if you are going to build such a shell and the implementation is easy for you to build as you say, I would recommend to build it, than depend on another library as you would build to add things as needed (more/less functionality, debugging etc)

Answer (score 0):

**[ArgumentTokenizer](http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/git_repo/ci/master/tree/drjava/src/edu/rice/cs/util/ArgumentTokenizer.java) from DrJava parses command line in a way  Bourne shell and its derivatives do**.

It properly supports escapes, so `bash -c 'echo "\"escaped '\''single'\'' quote\""'` gets tokenized into `[bash, -c, echo "\"escaped 'single' quote\""]`.

Answer (score -1):

Build the args[] back into a string, then tokenize using regexp:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String commandline = "";
    for(String arg : args) {
        commandline += arg;
        commandline += " ";
    }
    System.out.println(commandline);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*").matcher(commandline);
    while (m.find())
        list.add(m.group(1)); // Add .replace("\"", "") to remove surrounding quotes.


    System.out.println(list);
}
```

The latter part I took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/split-string-on-spaces-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-world-as).