# How can I parse CLI options using Clikt in a Compose Desktop app without executing the run function?

Tags: kotlin, command-line-interface, clikt

I'd like to use Clikt to parse database search arguments from a `TextField` in a Compose Desktop app, but in the documentation all the examples seem to include the `run` function like this:

```
class Filter : CliktCommand() {    
    val firstName: String? by option()
    val timeframe: String? by option().choice("any", "today", "week")
    override fun run() = Unit
}
```

Is there a way to just parse a string and get the resulting options so that I can use them for other purposes without running the command itself? I'm thinking about something like this (pseudocode):

```
val filter = CliktEtc.parse(argv).as(Filter::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. There's a `parse` method that populates the properties:

```
val argv = Commandline.translateCommandline("--first-name bob --timeframe today")
val result = Filter().apply { parse(argv) }
```

Since I'm using a plain string for it I also need something to parse that string, but unfortunatelly neither Clikt nor picocli support plain strings (only arrays) so I added the `org.apache.ant` as a dependency. That's where the [`Commandline` from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260112/235671) comes from.