# Get arguments like normal windows cmd does

Tags: c#, string, command-line, command-line-arguments

I was wondering if there is a way (built-in or implemented by a third party) to get a string and convert it in a string array like the Windows Cmd converts the arguments given to an application.
So if I write for example `goat "evil goat" -g`, I want the string to convert to an array with three cells (`goat`, `evil goat` (not sure if quotation marks remain, but I think not), `-g`). I know I can implement it by hand, but I wonder if there is some way to do it automatically.

In case anyone is wondering, this is for a command-interpreter and the strings will be read from a `TextBox.Text`, using a `Button`.

Any link with relevant information is welcome!

Comment: See [Split string containing command-line parameters into string in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/298830/2861476)

Comment: @MCND will check it out momentarily, thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to do what you want to do as follows:

```
public static List<string> GetCommandLineArguments(string commandline){
    var arguments = Regex.Matches(commandline, @"[\""].+?[\""]|[^ ]+")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();
    return arguments;
}
```

Comment: Woah, this is an old question. Lemme try that out real quick! - This is probably what I ended up doing back when I asked this. Thanks anyways for the help! :)