# Split (NOT PARSE) a string into command line args C#

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-arguments

Salutations,

I have what seems to be a simple problem but is very much not. I want to take a string and split it into command line arguments. I have been Googling this question for weeks and can't find anything that suits my needs.

For example, the line:
`--foo=bar -foo="bar test" --foo "bar \"test\"" --foo bar`

Would split into: **(in this order)**

- `--foo=bar`
- `-foo=bar test`
- `--foo`
- `bar "test"`
- `--foo`
- `bar`

**EDIT**

Yes I realize --foo is use more that once. This is splitting/tokenizing. Not parsing, that's the next step. I don't care if that would error when i go to parse. What i want to do RIGHT NOW is get the string into an array state that i can then feed into Mono.Options

**EDIT 2**

Read the example. That is what I am trying to accomplish. **JUST** that.

Comment: Did you create an MCVE?

Comment: Why do you want to split the args at all? This is usually automatically done when you execute your app using the console. However for parsing args there are many tools out there, for instance CommandLine-parser.

Comment: @BugFinder that answer is for parsing. Not for tokenizing/spiltting

Comment: There are many nuget packages that deal with command line arguments, see https://twitter.com/JamesNK/status/778088889588281345

Comment: Take a look at [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx) if you simply want to get the arguments your program was start with, or the duplicate otherwise.

Comment: Command line parsing is *NOT* done automatically. That's why there are libraries like NDesk, CommandLineParse and now, .NET's own System.CommandLine

Comment: @HimBromBeere this is not a one shot application. Command strings will be supplied from a socket connection

Comment: use a real command-line parser, like https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline

Comment: @Cole - better be clear inside the question that you don't get this from the actual command line but want to duplicate the parsing the OS does.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the OS doesn't do any parsing. Parsing is a lot more than just splitting individual tokens. .NET even has it's own [System.CommandLine](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/src/System.CommandLine) library now, for exactly this reason. A command line parser should return a `string[4]` array for `foo` given this command line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The commandline-tools all just get information from an array of stings into something meaningfull. However as far as I understand OP he needs to get this *array*. So the question is not on interpreting the information stored in an array, but to build it. Thus the duplicate and all solutions mentioning external tools won´t fit here. I´m voting to close this question as unclear.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - but the OP just wants to duplicate the splitting, with the processing of (escaped) quotes. Maybe then he needs an options parser but that's not in scope.

Comment: @Cole check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298830/split-string-containing-command-line-parameters-into-string-in-c-sharp) Tokenizing a command line isn't trivial using String.Split or regular expressions. A character-based parser is far easier. Windows also has a Win32 API function for this, `CommandLineToArgvW`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos tried that already. Unfortunately doesn't work with equal signs
`--foo="bar hello"` becomes `--foo="bar`, `hello`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Your last link is a good duplicate-candidate. Unfortunately I already voted to close this question.

Comment: @Cole you should be able to modify that parser according to your requirements, since it allows you to specify in code the split condition

Comment: @HimBromBeere voted to close THIS question?

Comment: you might want to look at this: `Utils.StartArgs.cs` @ https://github.com/BananaAcid/Selfcontained-C-Sharp-WPF-compatible-utility-classes/blob/master/Utils.StartArgs.cs ... it does split all kinds of comandline argument styles - quotes are handled by windows.

Answer (score -4):

If you are running a console application, the command line arguments are passed to Main method (String[] args).

Anyway, if you want to split your arguments, assuming that arguments are in one string variable, you can do this:

```
var arguments = "--foo=bar -foo=\"bar test\" --foo \"bar \"test\" --foo bar";

var options = arguments.Split(new String[] { "-", "--" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Output
// [0]: "foo=bar "
// [1]: "foo=\"bar test\" "
// [2]: "foo \"bar \"test\" "
// [3]: "foo bar"
```

[image]

Comment: This would also split "bar test\"

Comment: You need to review overloads for Split method, with this line of code: var array = arguments.Split(new String[] { "-", "--" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); you get 4 arguments

Comment: Parsing a command line is a bit trickier than simply splitting a string. For example, this command line contains *four* values for the single parameter `foo`. Besides, a good parser should be able to handle verbs, verb arguments and different parameter identifiers  lie `/`, `-` and `--`. It should be able to handle quoted values, which a Split can't do. Even a regex would have trouble with this

Comment: And all that should have an easy to use API, which is why command line parsing is done with libraries like .NET's System.CommandLine, NDesk, or CommandLineParser

Comment: @H.Herzl Your method would split `-foo="bar hello"` into `-foo="hello` **AND** `hello"`

Comment: Please review my answer, I attached one screenshot; let me know if is useful.

Comment: The point is this: you can split your string with one array string and not only with one char or string

Comment: I believe that you should try to design the command line arguments for one of your applications first, before you realize why parsing means more than string splitting. So you got some strings. What do these mean? What is the parameter's name? Will you split again? Even then, how are you going to assign values to actual variables or method parameters?

Comment: Your edit comes closer but still not good enough. You will have to split on whitespace and  deal with escaped quotes somehow.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - you really should read the question again.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I had to create command line argumens for several utilities so I understand that parsing is much more than just getting at the tokens

Answer (score -5):

Just simply use [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

This will give you a array of strings which represent the command line arguments

Comment: Environment Variables are something completely different than command line arguments. Command Line Arguments can be fetched with `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`.

Comment: sry...ment this  :(

Comment: Still not what the OP wants...

Comment: The OP already has a command line. The problem is, how do you *parse* it, ie get meaningful data out of it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if by parse you mean split/tokenize then yes. You are correct

Comment: @Cole I mean more than than - recognize and return verbs and parameters, recognize that `foo` is multivalued, allow verbose names etc. What you get from an actual library. Which is what you should look into