# Is there a way to call .NET's console app native command line parser directly?

Tags: .net, console-application, command-line-arguments

I've found that the native command line parser used by .NET console apps serves my needs well, especially how it interprets text enclosed within quotes as a single argument. Is it possible to make a call to this parser directly?

Comment: Command line parsing actually tends to be a horrific mess because different OSes have different views on who should be doing the parsing (the OS itself? The shell? The application? An unholy mix?) so be careful what you ask for. [Then there's this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/298830/4137916).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for System.CommandLine

Please check this article that talks about the System.CommandLine architecture.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline

The System.CommandLine sources are open and available at:
https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong I think there a batch file that you can call

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

You can call the first for 32 bits and the second for 64 bits, after calling this batch file you'll be able to use the compiler directly.